# Java REGEX - Not able to remove content inside tag

Tags: java, regex

This is my input text:

```
[QUOTE=SynapseBreak;104047835]Armchio de dragon is satki dragon lai de leh

[URL="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shiportal.hwzreader&referrer=utm_source%3Dsignature%26utm_medium%3Dforum"]Sent from &#27402;&#24535;-&#40845; using GAGT[/URL][/QUOTE]
why satki ? tell me :s13:

[QUOTE=articated;104047854]I not sad lah
U happy i happy kym

Just for fun loh :s12:
[ms]&#33258;&#24478;&#25105;&#35722;&#25104;&#20102;&#29399;&#23630;&#65292;&#23601;&#20877;&#20063;&#27794;&#26377;&#20154;&#25954;&#36393;&#22312;&#25105;&#38957;&#19978;&#20102; HardwareZone Forums app[/ms][/QUOTE]
today arti jin sweet make me happy :s12:

[QUOTE=Iandao;104047967]Gg mbs now...[/QUOTE]
go there jiak simi ??
```

I am trying to remove all the content inside [QUOTE] [/QUOTE] tags and the tags themselves.

I want the output to be :

```
why satki ? tell me :s13: today arti jin sweet make me happy :s12: go there jiak simi ??
```

The code i tried is:

```
string.replaceAll("\\[QUOTE.*\\[/QUOTE\\]", "")
```

Comment: So, the issue is you match too much? Or almost nothing? Try [`"(?s)\\[QUOTE=.*?\\[/QUOTE\\]"`](https://regex101.com/r/zbfTse/2). Btw, are there any *nested* `[QUOTE]` tags?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew! Your patterns works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you may use the following fix for your pattern *only if the input does not contain nested `[QUOTE]` tages*.

A `.` in your regex does not match line breaks, and `.*` is too greedy, i.e. will match up to the last occurrence of `[/QUOTE]` on a line/in a string.

Use lazy dot matching with the `Pattern.DOTALL` inline modifier (embedded flag option) `(?s)` that will force the `.` to match *any* char:

```
"(?s)\\[QUOTE=.*?\\[/QUOTE\\]" 
 ^^^^         ^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zbfTse/2).

Or, unroll the lazy dot (to make the pattern find matches faster) as:

```
"\\[QUOTE=[^\\[]*(?:\\[(?!/QUOTE\\])[^\\[]*)*\\[/QUOTE\\]"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zbfTse/3).

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/4BrHDo):

```
String pat = "\\[QUOTE=[^\\[]*(?:\\[(?!/QUOTE])[^\\[]*)*\\[/QUOTE]";
String str = "[QUOTE=SynapseBreak;104047835]Armchio de dragon is satki dragon lai de leh\n\n[URL=\"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shiportal.hwzreader&referrer=utm_source%3Dsignature%26utm_medium%3Dforum\"]Sent from &#27402;&#24535;-&#40845; using GAGT[/URL][/QUOTE]\nwhy satki ? tell me :s13:\n[QUOTE=articated;104047854]I not sad lah\nU happy i happy kym\n\nJust for fun loh :s12:\n[ms]&#33258;&#24478;&#25105;&#35722;&#25104;&#20102;&#29399;&#23630;&#65292;&#23601;&#20877;&#20063;&#27794;&#26377;&#20154;&#25954;&#36393;&#22312;&#25105;&#38957;&#19978;&#20102; HardwareZone Forums app[/ms][/QUOTE]\ntoday arti jin sweet make me happy :s12:\n\n[QUOTE=Iandao;104047967]Gg mbs now...[/QUOTE]\ngo there jiak simi ??'";
String res = str.replaceAll(pat, "");
System.out.println(res); 
// => why satki ? tell me :s13:
//
//    today arti jin sweet make me happy :s12:
//
//
//     go there jiak simi ??'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not taking new lines into account. This is done by adding (?s) at the beginning.

```
string.replaceAll("(?s)\\[QUOTE.*?\\[/QUOTE\\]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?s)\\[QUOTE.*?\\[/QUOTE\\]
```

Try the above RegEx. It will work.